# Team Foundation Server / TEE Check-In To Folder

Tags: php, eclipse, tfs, tfsbuild, team-explorer-everywhere

I utilize Eclipse with Team Explorer Everywhere to connect to a Team Foundation Server, whose primary purpose is to serve as a repository for my PHP application.

Rather than running a build on check-in, I'd like to have TFS dump the latest copies of the files to a specified folder, without building.

Is this action possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the build template\script to just perform the copy operation.

Comment: This is a good solution.  A continuous integration build might be a better choice for this than a gated build, because CI runs after the files are checked in (gated before).

Comment: Thanks for the tip - could you recommend any resources that explain in detail how to set this up? @ShawTerwilliger - it will likely run as CI, good thinking.